# Dynamic Query Object

Tags: java

I am using JAVA with sql I want to create query object name dynamically based on loop

example

```
Query query1;
Query query2;
Query query3....
```

the number 1,2,3 comes from variable i incremented in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use a `Map<String, Query>` where you can then do:

```
Map<String, Query> queries = new HashMap<String, Query>();
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    queries.put("query" + i, new Query());
}
```

I'd just like to point out that this is a code smell, and you should probably wonder why you need to create so many queries.